# image control sliding on source change in view (flex mobile app)

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air

i have a simple xml gallery ( ViewNavigatorApplication ), first view is thumb and second view named as "SlideView".
All views change are happening nicely using SlideTransition to each other from "navigation content area buttons"
SlideView has an image control, showing each image at a time. In slide view , i detect slide gestures and it change source property of image control and new image pops up.
Problem is, i want new image to slide in each time, when source property (which is binded to current slide). any ideas?

current slide view basic code is like

```
protected function swipeGestureHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
            {
                if (event.offsetX == -1) {
                    _dm.currItem.nextSlide();
                }
                else if (event.offsetX == 1 ) {
                    _dm.currItem.prevSlide();
                }
            }
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>
<s:Image id="slideImage" visible="true" width="100%" height="85%" 
             source="{_dm.currItem.currSlide}" />
```

i tried defining some effects in fx declaration area like

```
<fx:Declarations>

        <s:Wipe id="wipeOut" direction="left" duration="500" />
        <s:Wipe id="wipeIn" direction="right" duration="500" />


        <s:Move id="MoveLeft" target="{slideImage}" xBy="300" duration="500"/>
        <s:Move id="MoveRight" target="{slideImage}" xBy="-300" duration="500"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
```

and using them in image control like

```
hideEffect="{MoveLeft}" showEffect="{MoveRight}"
```

but its of no use...
any ideas, please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. The show/hide events won't get generated when you change the `Image`'s source. Instead, trigger these effects manually yourself when the user makes a swipe gesture.

- on swipe gesture: `MoveLeft.play()` (assumes that the `target` of the effect is the Image)
- now the image is off screen, set the new source for the image
- `MoveRight.play()`

To polish this effect, you might want to have two `Image` objects in your view. When transitioning to the next image, you can set the source of the other `Image` object to the new  value before playing any effects (to try and pre-load the image).

Comment: thanks, it helped. worked out nicely. let me know if someone needs finished code sample.

Comment: i am trying to do something similar. if you can send me your code sample this would be greate